# Hide if there is no data in angular

Tags: angularjs

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, values) in myData">
        <td> {{ key}} </td>
        <td>
            <div ng-repeat="item in values| limitTo:limit | filter: {source: sourceFilter}" ng-include="'templates/item.html'"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

With the above code I looping through the keys/values, where key is a string and value is an array. I am filtering the values by the `'source'` property - this means that sometimes some keys have no items displayed. I would like to hide all of the rows that do not have any items.

I have tried using custom filters, and `ng-show`/`ng-hide`, but as I am an angular noob I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Could someone show me an example of how I can achieve this ? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, values) in myData" 
        ng-hide="(values | filter: {source: sourceFilter).length == 0">
        <td> {{ key}} </td>
        <td>
            <div ng-repeat="item in values| limitTo:limit | filter: {source: sourceFilter}" ng-include="'templates/item.html'"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Some example in <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BfAP72oa9Zw0nPFG4dlp?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: @sree well, this answer was for AngularJS, not Angular 4. Pls read the question

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, values) in myData" ng-hide="itemValues.length == 0">
    <td> {{ key}} </td>
    <td>
        <div ng-repeat="item in values = (itemValues | limitTo:limit | filter: {source: sourceFilter})" ng-include="'templates/item.html'"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually make a directive that handles this case, that way I can use it more than once and I am not repeating code.  Something like:

```
.directive('nodata', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                if (element[0].innerText === '') {
                    element[0].innerText = '–';
                    element.css({
                        # use css here to display none or change color etc
                        # at your preference   
                    });
                }
            }, 0);
        }
    };
}])
```

Then you can just add `nodata>{{ yourAngular.binding }}` to your html element.