# AngularJS Filter performs search by value attribute only and not text of html elements?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to understand the angularJS filter mechanics to try and extend its initial functionality. Currently from what I can tell, when you perform the filter, it will search the value attribute on each html element for a match. This works all great in most cases. Where this falls apart is dropdown lists. If you set the text of an option to `Hello world` and the value = `1`, the search is looking at the value attribute of the `<option>` instead of the text. This breaks the expected results thus why I need to find a way to make the filter include the Text properties of dropdown lists. Looking for advice on how to handle this or just further details of the filter function underneath. Below is the code i am trying to apply this too.

```
<div ng-app="CategoryFieldApproversApp">

Search:<input id="txtSearch" ng-model="search" type="text" placeholder="Search" />

@using (Html.BeginForm("CategoryFieldApprovers", "Maintenance", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div ng-controller="CategoryFieldApproversCtrl">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="1%"></th>
                    <th ng-click="sort('Name')" width="200">Category Field</th>
                    <th ng-click="sort('Name')" width="150">Approver</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr dir-paginate="categoryFieldApprover in categoryFieldApprovers|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|itemsPerPage:5" ng-show="ddlVisibility(categoryFieldApprover)">
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="CategoryFieldApprovers[{{$index}}].CategoryFieldApproverID" ng-model="categoryFieldApprover.CategoryFieldApproverID" value="{{categoryFieldApprover.CategoryFieldApproverID}}" />
                        <input type="hidden" id="hdnIsDirty" name="CategoryFieldApprovers[{{$index}}].IsDirty" value="{{categoryFieldApprover.IsDirty}}" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="hdnCategoryFieldID" type="hidden" name="CategoryFieldApprovers[{{$index}}].CategoryFieldID" value="{{categoryFieldApprover.CategoryFieldID}}" />
                        <select ng-model="categoryFieldApprover.CategoryFieldID" ng-options="categoryField.CategoryFieldID as categoryField.Name for categoryField in categoryFields | filter:{Name :search}"></select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="hdnApproverOneUserID" type="hidden" name="CategoryFieldApprovers[{{$index}}].ApproverOneUserID" value="{{categoryFieldApprover.ApproverOneUserID}}" />
                        <select ng-model="categoryFieldApprover.ApproverOneUserID" ng-options="user.UserID as user.DisplayName for user in users | filter:{DisplayName :search}"></select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" ng-click="remove($index)" ng-show="categoryFieldApprover.ShowRemove" value="Remove" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <dir-pagination-controls max-size="5"
                                 direction-links="true"
                                 boundary-links="true">
        </dir-pagination-controls>
        <br />
        <a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="add()">Add Field Approver</a>
        <input class="btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="save()" type="button" value="Save" />
    </div>
}
</div>

<script>
var App = angular.module('CategoryFieldApproversApp', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']).controller('CategoryFieldApproversCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.get("@Url.Action("GetCategoryFieldApprovers", "Maintenance")").success(function (response) {
        $scope.categoryFieldApprovers = response;  //ajax request to fetch data into $scope.data
    });

    $http.get("@Url.Action("GetCategoryFields", "Maintenance")").success(function (response) {
        $scope.categoryFields = response;  //ajax request to fetch data into $scope.data
    });

    $http.get("@Url.Action("GetUsers", "Maintenance")").success(function (response) {
        $scope.users = response;  //ajax request to fetch data into $scope.data
    });

    $scope.sort = function (keyname) {
        $scope.sortKey = keyname;   //set the sortKey to the param passed
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse; //if true make it false and vice versa
    }

    $scope.remove = function (index) {
        $scope.categoryFieldApprovers.splice(index, 1);
    };

    $scope.add = function () {
        $scope.categoryFieldApprovers.splice(0, 0, {
            CategoryFieldApproverID: 0,
            CategoryFieldID: 0,
            ApproverOneUserID: 0,
            ApproverTwoUserID: 0,
            ShowRemove: true
        });
    };

    $scope.save = function () {
        $('tbody tr').find('.ng-dirty').each(function (i, dirtyElement) {
            $(dirtyElement).closest('tr').find('#hdnIsDirty').val(true);
        });

        $('form').submit();
    };

    $scope.ddlVisibility = function (categoryFieldApprover) {

        if ($('#txtSearch').val() != "" && (categoryFieldApprover.CategoryFieldID == null && categoryFieldApprover.ApproverOneUserID == null)) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
});

</script>
```

UPDATES: Removed the |filter:search from the tr element. Then added the filter:{Name: search} for each dropdown. It will now correctly filter and show/hide rows for those that pass the check. The only remaining problem now is that when the filter function executes, if the dropdowns selected item fails the test, it sets the selected index to 0 which is the blank item. How can I prevent it from changing the selection just because it failed to be included from the filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this small demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/amighty/0mk6zmmd/43/). If you are looking for same functionality then you just need to specify property inside filter which you want to search.

> filter:{Name :search}

e.g.

```
<select ng-model="categoryFieldApprover.CategoryFieldID" ng-options="categoryField.CategoryFieldID as categoryField.Name for categoryField in categoryFields | filter:{Name :search}"></select>
```

Comment: When i run your demo, the dropdown clears out the selection once you type in the number part of the name. Type in "test" and then when you keypress the number, the selection disappears. I added this code in mine and when i perform the search, it has similar effects where it clears the selection of one of the drop downs in the grid and doesn't filter properly still.

Comment: making progress!!! I'll update the html code above now so you can see what i have along with edit notes.

Comment: I dont know how your page looks or works completely but to hide TR itself you will have to use ng-show  or ng-if attribute on TR tag with expression. That expression should return true or false based on content or you can make use of additional filter on row with same search.

Comment: This page is a maintenance screen. It's a simple grid that the user will be selecting/updating the selections for each dropdownlist in each cell of every row to save to the database. The search feature is there so they can quickly find the item they want to change in the table.

Comment: Please check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21731161/hide-if-there-is-no-data-in-angular. It will give you better idea. I think you need similar logic.

Comment: Does it matter that i don't have the filter applied to all elements for each row? Learning angular as i go so sorry for dumb questions :D

Comment: filters applied to each td inside tr will work on td only so similar logic you need to apply on tr so that it removes itself once no data left to display on each td. The expression for ng-hide can be small or big based on each filter inside tr.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103768/discussion-between-user1732364-and-amighty).

Comment: I have created this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/1WZtL5gbvpGVfjkGwLuE?p=preview. It should help you.... You need to add  ng-hide="(categoryFields|filter:{Name:search}).length == 0" on TR. Also add aditional condition inside if you need any.

Comment: The solution you gave me does perform the filtering correct so i went ahead and marked it as answered. The ones that fail the filter test set the selected index to 0 which basically is a no go on this approach. I'm going to take a break and look at it from some more perspectives to solve this.